# CSS clip only height dimension

Tags: css, web, clip

I have this coded into my css file. I want the image to clip at a certain height, but I want it to spread the entire width of the screen. By setting the width really wide, this creates more problems including the image spreading larger than the rest of the material on the page.

```
clip: rect(0px, 4800px, 560px, 0px);
```

Comment: Try 100vw instead of 4800px. If that doesn't work, we need a [mcve].

Comment: That did it, Thanks

Comment: @MrLister Post as an answer and I'll mark it correct